# Python regex replace words within brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

How to replace word within brackets with empty string for repetitive words?

```
import re

resource_path = '/mdm/v1/{appId}/templates/{templateId}'
clean_resource_path = re.sub(r"\s*\{[^()]*\}$", '', resource_path)

print(clean_resource_path)
```

I get output as `/mdm/v1/` but ideally I want output as `/mdm/v1/templates`.
I know the my regex is replacing everything between `{}` with empty quotes, but I want only to the next available quote.

Comment: `re.sub(r"/\{[^}]*?\}", '', resource_path)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re
resource_path = '/mdm/v1/{appId}/templates/{templateId}'
clean_resource_path = re.sub(r"/{\w*}*", '', resource_path)

print(clean_resource_path)
```

output

```
/mdm/v1/templates
```